# Obtener el booleano de un DataGridView

Tags: c#

Buenos dias! Tengo mi dataGrid que se llena con datos de mi base de datos e hice una columna adicional del tipo checkbox para que dados ciertos pedidos marcados se facturen. Pero lo que me sucede es que tengo que actualizar un lbl acorde a los pedidos seleccionados con sus respectivos montos y solo se me actualiza cuando la celda seleccionada pierde el foco y necesito que sea cuando selecciono el valor true o false directamente. Eh intentado el siguiente codigo atado al evento dataGridView1_CellClick pero no funciona, el valor siempre esta desactualiado. Si hago click en el valor es siempre el que tenia y no el nuevo.

```
        decimal totalSelected = 0;
        dataGridView1.Focus();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell = row.Cells[0] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;

            if (cell.Value != null)
            {
                if (cell.Value == cell.TrueValue)
                {
                    totalSelected += Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[3].Value);
                }
            }
        }
        lblTotalToPaid.Text = totalSelected.ToString("$0.00", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es, en el evento `CellClick` ejecutar un `CommitEdit`. De esa manera se dispara el evento `CellValueChanged` que ya contiene el valor correcto. Sería algo asi:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}



private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, 
DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     //Aqui tu código
}
```

De todas maneras, el código que utilizas no se si es muy eficiente, ya que cada vez que modifiques un checkbox vas a recorrer todas las filas del `DataGridView`. Yo pensaría en almacenar el valor `totalSelected` en una propiedad local y solo sumar/restar el valor de la fila del checkbox.